# Android - How do I save the state of my ImageView boolean value of a ListView Item List?

Tags: android, checkbox, imageview, sharedpreferences, listviewitem

It's my first time trying to make an App that is basically a checklist that helps me keep track of i.e. collected items. Much like a checklist in a game. I am veeeeery inexperienced with Android so I found some template that I modified for my own need. I'm basically using two .png files (checked and unchecked box) as ImageView which upon clicking change into one another, thus imitating a basic checkbox. Aparently this method worked best for me, even though I thought a normal checkbox object would be easier. When i used regular checkbox objects the status of 'checked' moved throughout the list... And with this ImageView method the checked boxes remained the same as the ones I really checked.

So I figured how to generate a List. Later on I will manually change the list to the Items/Names/etc. as I want that won't be a problem. The App also manages to let me select multiple Items and the items remain checked even after its onPause.
The problem I face now is that upon distroying the app on the device and on restarting the app, all the checked Items are now unchecked. That means that the information that the item was check was not stored at all.

I would be so happy if someone can help me with completing the code... I have no idea how to store the information of which Item in List was checked and let alone be reloaded upon onCreate.

Here is ***activity_main.xml***, which is basically the ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    tools:context="com.multiselect.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Next up is the ***list_view_item.xml*** where the Name, Subtitle and Checkbox ImageView are declared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp">

//NAME//
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_check_box"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

//SUB
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv_user_sub"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_user_name"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_name"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/sub"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry" />

//Checkbox
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_check_box"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/check"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So then I have a basic ***UserModel.java*** with all the Getters and Setters.

```
package com.multiselect;

public class UserModel {

    private boolean isSelected;
    private String userName;
    private String userSub;

    //create constructor and getter setter


    public UserModel(boolean isSelected, String userName, String userSub) {
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userSub = userSub;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        isSelected = selected;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserSub() {
        return userSub;
    }

    public void setUserSub(String userSub) {
        this.userSub = userSub;
    }
}
```

Then I know I need an ***CustomAdapter.java*** for what I wanna do. I have a ViewHolder inside together with an updater for the checle items.

```
    package com.multiselect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;   
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    List<UserModel> users;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    //short to create constructer using alt+insert or rightclick - generate - constructor

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, List<UserModel> users) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.users = users;

        inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(view == null){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, viewGroup, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvUserName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name);
            holder.tvUserSub = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_sub);
            holder.ivCheckBox = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_check_box);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }else
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        UserModel model = users.get(i);

        holder.tvUserName.setText(model.getUserName());
        holder.tvUserSub.setText(model.getUserSub());

        if (model.isSelected()) {
                holder.ivCheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked);
        }
        else
                holder.ivCheckBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check);

        return view;
    }

    public void updateRecords(List<UserModel> users) {
        this.users = users;

        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    class ViewHolder{

        TextView tvUserName;
        TextView tvUserSub;
        ImageView ivCheckBox;


    }
}
```

...And ***MainActivity.java***:

```
package com.multiselect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        final List<UserModel> users = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
            users.add(new UserModel(false, "Name "+(i), "Subtitle " + (i)));
        }


        final CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, users);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                UserModel model = users.get(i);


                if (model.isSelected())
                    model.setSelected(false);

                else
                    model.setSelected(true);

                users.set(i, model);

                //now update adapter
                adapter.updateRecords(users);


            }

        });

    }

}
```

And now I know I should use SharedPreferences in the ***MainActivity.java*** but I don't know how in this specific example... 
Especially when I try it out with what other people said the app just crashes either as soon as I check something or when I just try to Run the app. I'm literally not good enough for this and I really want to know how something I normally take for granted (that an app remembers whats been don in it) is done programmatically.

I hope that someone can complete my Code so that the app remembers which box was checked and reloads that upon onCreate...

Comment: don't u maintain any unique attribute in user model. Then there can be duplicates ?

Comment: I don't really understand sorry... I'm still having a problrm with saving the state of user model. I guess the user list is generated everytime onCreate and overwrites the state before. Im thinking about making a checkpoint to see if there is any information stored. Another idea i had is using a jason file :/ but still need to learn how to do that for my example

Comment: I updated my answer to resolve ur list update issue. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

First, u need to add a unique attribute to your user model. like userId

```
private int userId
```

then add setters and getters like other attributes. I think then u can use tinyDB to stores recent value of this userId. Then u can increment this userId when new user model added.

```
 TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
 int recentid = tinydb.getInt(recentUserId) == null ? 0:tinydb.getInt(recentUserId)
 tinydb.putInt("recentUserId",recentid++);
 userModel1.setUserId(recentid)
```

After that, You can create array list with checked ids. If the user checked any post then update that list. If user unchecked that list then remove id from list.

```
 List<int> checkedList = new ArrayList<>;
    checkedList.add(..userid);
```

Then u can update TinyDb when you update that checked list using below command.

```
tinydb.putList("checkedIdList", chekcedList);
```

when app starting state u need to call this tinydb and get checked list using below command

```
  tinydb.getList("checkedIdList");
```

then u can update your list with checked and unchecked states

PS: u can nevigate to https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo this and get idea about tinydb as well. It is kind of good improvement of shared preferences

---

You need to do following thing in onCrete method to avoid always update checkList.

```
  List<int> checkedList = new ArrayList<>;

  if(tinydb.getList("checkedIdList")!= null){
      checkedList = tinydb.getList("checkedIdList")
  }
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the fast answer! I see. So TinyDB might be better for such a thing. Where shall i put all the code? I guess the useriD declaration and setter and getters must go to the UserModel.java, but what about the rest? Any rules for that?

Comment: User id setter and getter should move into a usermodel. Get userid from tiny db part and store recent id part should be moved into place where u create new user model. Add checked one, remove uncheked one and update checkedlist in tinydb should move to where u trigger that radio button action. Get checked list and update list in ui should move into onCreate method